# You don't have permission to access /marcon/assets/images/pic.jpg in apache php

Tags: php, apache

I am getting this error
You don't have permission to access /marcon/assets/images/pic.jpg in apache php on my local Fedora 17, php,mysql and apache(not Xampp installation).
This error is occuring for any new files that I am copying to the directory.The older files /marcon/assets/images/header.jpg are accessible just fine. I checked the permissions and they are 777 (now) but still doesn't work. 
This is a very wierd error. The subdirectory and other images work fine. Just the newer files don't work

This happens when I embed it as an image as well as when I access it directly. It works for all other files in the directory. Not just the newer ones

EDIT: **Ironically this problem doesn't occur if i check the files into github and clone the project back again. Everything works hunky dory.**

Comment: You checked the permission of the file for which this error is coming or just the directory?

Comment: i did. I checked their peissions and made them all 777s. I am sure this is not a permissions ionssue. something to do with the server. I have faced this sort of problem before withuploading files(to a 777 directory) on this sytem, but never reached a solution

Comment: Is there any `.htaccess` or `directory`  directive which may restrict your access?

Comment: nope. I checked all that. The ironic thing is that when I check in the files into git, delete and reclone the whole project, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is SElinux issue:

Try

```
$ ls -Z file1
```

you should get something similar to:

```
drwxr-xr-x. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 scripts
```

if no try:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t  /marcon/assets/images
```

Comment: I got rid of Fedora and on ubuntu this doesnt happen, so I have no way to verify this. Thanks for answering